# KCQL query to push Influx line protocol points from kafka topic to InfluxDB

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I send influx line protocol points to a kafka-topic. I am able to read those points from kafka-cli . Now I want to insert all the points in the kafka-topic in InfluxDB. I configured kafka influxdb sink connector to push data into influxdb. I am not able to figure out the KCQL query to do that.

I tried

> Insert * from influx-topic

hoping it would push everything from topic to influxdb but I am getting parsing errors.

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to parse at line 1 due to mismatched input '*' expecting INTO
        at com.datamountaineer.kcql.Kcql$1.syntaxError(Kcql.java:330)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:41)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.notifyErrorListeners(Parser.java:544)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportInputMismatch(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:299)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportError(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:124)`

Note : I already have my data in line protocol format in the kafka topic, so I don't need to select specific fields . For now the topic has data of just one measurement , in future it may have data of multiple measurements.

I read through the docs for KCQL at |https://lenses.stream/1.0/lenses/connectors/kcql.html#kcql and still couldn't figure out what the correct query would look like. please help me form the query.